# UniWebView linker errors when compiling for iOS (using Unity 5, XCode 7.3.1 and iOS SDK 9.3)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview, unity-game-engine

I am using UniWebView 2 in a cross-platform application and while the app compiles and runs on Android, when building it for iOS, I get errors when building the project in XCode. I tried creating an empty project and compiling one of the UniWebView example scenes and got the same errors.

Said errors are as follows:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "__WebViewPlugin_EvaluateJS", referenced from:
      _WebViewObject__WebViewPlugin_EvaluateJS_m3600170591 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
      _WebViewObject__WebViewPlugin_EvaluateJS_m3600170591 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _WebViewObject__WebViewPlugin_EvaluateJS_m3600170591)
  "__WebViewPlugin_SetVisibility", referenced from:
      _WebViewObject__WebViewPlugin_SetVisibility_m1941317136 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
      _WebViewObject_SetVisibility_m1306909320 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
      _WebViewObject__WebViewPlugin_SetVisibility_m1941317136 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
      _WebViewObject_SetVisibility_m1306909320 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _WebViewObject__WebViewPlugin_SetVisibility_m1941317136)
  "__WebViewPlugin_SetMargins", referenced from:
      _WebViewObject__WebViewPlugin_SetMargins_m46209250 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
      _WebViewObject_SetMargins_m3594992190 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
      _WebViewObject__WebViewPlugin_SetMargins_m46209250 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
      _WebViewObject_SetMargins_m3594992190 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _WebViewObject__WebViewPlugin_SetMargins_m46209250)
  "__WebViewPlugin_LoadURL", referenced from:
      _WebViewObject__WebViewPlugin_LoadURL_m3058146388 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
      _WebViewObject__WebViewPlugin_LoadURL_m3058146388 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _WebViewObject__WebViewPlugin_LoadURL_m3058146388)
  "__WebViewPlugin_Destroy", referenced from:
      _WebViewObject__WebViewPlugin_Destroy_m2965791645 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
      _WebViewObject_OnDestroy_m852260632 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
      _WebViewObject__WebViewPlugin_Destroy_m2965791645 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
      _WebViewObject_OnDestroy_m852260632 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _WebViewObject__WebViewPlugin_Destroy_m2965791645)
  "__WebViewPlugin_SetFrame", referenced from:
      _WebViewObject__WebViewPlugin_SetFrame_m3791199226 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
      _WebViewObject_SetCenterPositionWithScale_m3707009509 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
      _WebViewObject__WebViewPlugin_SetFrame_m3791199226 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
      _WebViewObject_SetCenterPositionWithScale_m3707009509 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _WebViewObject__WebViewPlugin_SetFrame_m3791199226)
  "__WebViewPlugin_Init", referenced from:
      _WebViewObject__WebViewPlugin_Init_m1745555759 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
      _WebViewObject__WebViewPlugin_Init_m1745555759 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _WebViewObject__WebViewPlugin_Init_m1745555759)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The command that causes them is this:

```
Ld /Users/studentdeveloper/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cufatstjeeklntdglsasxcmmpkyu/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/ProductName normal armv7
    cd /Users/studentdeveloper/projects/UniWebViewTest/build/move_prefab_and_scripts_2
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.3.sdk -L/Users/studentdeveloper/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cufatstjeeklntdglsasxcmmpkyu/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos -L/Users/studentdeveloper/projects/UniWebViewTest/build/move_prefab_and_scripts_2 -L/Users/studentdeveloper/projects/UniWebViewTest/build/move_prefab_and_scripts_2/Libraries -F/Users/studentdeveloper/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cufatstjeeklntdglsasxcmmpkyu/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos -filelist /Users/studentdeveloper/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cufatstjeeklntdglsasxcmmpkyu/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/ProductName.LinkFileList -Xlinker -map -Xlinker /Users/studentdeveloper/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cufatstjeeklntdglsasxcmmpkyu/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/ProductName-LinkMap-normal-armv7.txt -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -dead_strip -fembed-bitcode-marker -weak_framework CoreMotion -weak-lSystem -stdlib=libc++ -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -framework CoreText -framework AudioToolbox -weak_framework AVFoundation -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreMedia -weak_framework CoreMotion -framework CoreVideo -framework Foundation -weak_framework iAd -framework MediaPlayer -framework OpenAL -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -liconv.2 -liPhone-lib -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/studentdeveloper/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cufatstjeeklntdglsasxcmmpkyu/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/ProductName_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/studentdeveloper/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cufatstjeeklntdglsasxcmmpkyu/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/ProductName
```

- I have kept the Plugins directory structure
- I use IL2CPP as the scripting backend
- I'm targeting the correct device, SDK and iOS version
- I have tried disabling *bitcode* and enabling *Preserve Private External Symbols* in the XCode project settings
- I managed to build and deploy on an iPad simulator(x86_64, since I'm building on a 64-bit Mac)
- [Here](https://github.com/gree/unity-webview/blob/master/plugins/WebViewObject.cs) is the WebViewObject.cs file where the methods in question are defined

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

WebViewPlugin is the Gree's unity web view, so it is not probably a UniWebView issue (they are different package).

You could try to remove the WebViewPlugin and related things from your project if you are not using them. And try again with only UniWebView.